# destroy a sessions in GAE webapp2 of inactive users

Tags: python, google-app-engine, session, webapp2

i developed my application with python and Google app and  webapp2 , i need to destroy the session if user not active a time determined
i tested this:

```
config['webapp2_extras.sessions'] = {
'secret_key': 'the_Key',
'session_max_age': 60
```

but this destroy the session whatever active or not,
it is possible to destroy just if it inactive

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Who decides if a user is inactive?

Typically, this happens on the client side. For example, you can have a listener that resets the "last action" timestamp after every native browser event, and a timer that checks if this timestamp is old enough to log out the user. If it is, your client should tell the server to destroy the session, and after that close the window or redirect a user to a home/login page.

Comment: thanks for your answer, this solution should  be in all pages of my application ? and for every redirect to this page from server i should test this variable ? sorry i don't understand how i can do that